# Redux: re-rendering children on store state update

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have started to learn `react` + `redux` recently. Prior to that I have not had experience with this sort of stack.
So I ran into a problem where I do not understand why child components do not get re-rendered when reducer returns new state.
[Full code on GITHUB](https://github.com/mdomasevicius/hadex-sandy/tree/feature/bootstrap-redux/apps/sandy-ui/)

This is my parent component [source on git](https://github.com/mdomasevicius/hadex-sandy/blob/feature/bootstrap-redux/apps/sandy-ui/src/js/components/warehouses/WarehousePage.js):

```
import React from "react"
import {connect} from "react-redux"

import {fetchWarehouses} from "../../actions/warehouseActions"

import WarehouseMenu from "./WarehouseMenu"
import WarehouseView from "./WarehouseView"
import WarehouseEdit from "./WarehouseEdit"

@connect((store) => {
    return {
        warehouses: store.warehouses.warehouses,
        selectedWarehouse: store.warehouses.selectedWarehouse,
        isSelected: store.warehouses.isSelected,
        warehouseCount: store.warehouses.warehouseCount,
    }
})
export default class WarehousePage extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchWarehouses())
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-2">
                        Warehouses ({this.props.warehouseCount}):
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                        <WarehouseMenu warehouseList={this.props.warehouses} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <WarehouseView test={this.props.isSelected} selectedWarehouse={this.props.selectedWarehouse} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <WarehouseEdit />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

And these are children [source on git](https://github.com/mdomasevicius/hadex-sandy/blob/feature/bootstrap-redux/apps/sandy-ui/src/js/components/warehouses/WarehouseMenu.js):

```
import React from "react"
import store from "../../store"
import {fetchOne} from "../../actions/warehouseActions"

export default class WarehouseMenu extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

select(id) {
    store.dispatch(fetchOne(id))
}

render() {
    const {warehouseList} = this.props.warehouseList

    if (!warehouseList) {
        return <button className="btn btn-success" key="new_warehouse">+</button>
    }

    const mappedWarehouses = warehouseList.map(wh => <button onClick={this.select.bind(this, wh.id)} className="btn btn-default" key={wh.id}>{wh.name}</button>)
    mappedWarehouses.push(<button className="btn btn-success" key="new_warehouse">+</button>)
    return (
        <div className="btn-group">
            {mappedWarehouses}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

And [source on git](https://github.com/mdomasevicius/hadex-sandy/blob/feature/bootstrap-redux/apps/sandy-ui/src/js/components/warehouses/WarehouseView.js):

```
import React from "react"
import store from "../../store"
import {deleteWarehouse, fetchWarehouses} from "../../actions/warehouseActions"

export default class WarehouseView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        const {test, selectedWarehouse} = this.props

        if (!test) {
            return null
        }

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-2">
                       ID
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                        {selectedWarehouse.id}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-2">
                        Name
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-10">
                        {selectedWarehouse.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-12">
                        <button className="btn btn-warning">EDIT</button>
                        <button onClick={this.deleteWarehouse.bind(this, selectedWarehouse.id)} className="btn btn-danger">DELETE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    deleteWarehouse(id) {
        store.dispatch(deleteWarehouse(id))
    }

}
```

So whenever I dispatch `deleteWarehouse` I want `WarehouseMenu` to rerender since the state of `store.warehouses.warehouses` changes. I do not get the expected result. Only `WarehousePage` rerenders (e.g. `store.warehouses.warehouseCount`). I've tried `@connect`int store to child components but did not seem to get the desired result also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alterning the `warehouses` property inside your `warehouseReducers.js` when a `DELETE_WAREHOUSE_FULFILLED` action is dispatched, but you do alter the `warehouseCount`

Answer (score 1):

Your delete action:

```
export function deleteWarehouse(id) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.delete(`/api/sandy/api/warehouses/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                    type: "DELETE_WAREHOUSE_FULFILLED",
                    payload: null
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
            })
    }
}
```

never updates the state to remove the deleted warehouse from the `state.warehouses` array in `warehouseReducers.js`:

```
case "DELETE_WAREHOUSE_FULFILLED": {
    return {...state,
        selectedWarehouse: null,
        isSelected: false,
        warehouseCount: state.warehouseCount - 1
    }
}
```